# Tail a log to another device

Tags: logging, storage, tail

We have a network wifi device which is tracking vehicles and it is having some connection issues so we need to run a tcp dump and let it run for a long time, maybe 8 - 12 hours.

The network device is running a cut down version of Linux and the hard drive in it is only 64 mb

It talks to a Ubuntu server running 12.04 - which has plenty of space on the hard drive, so we would like to ship the results from the tcp dump onto it, instead of using the local drive

The tcp dump command we are currently using is

```
tcpdump  -n  -s 64 -i  r1_ap1  -w  filename.pcap
```

We can't map a network drive (samba is not installed).  It's a closed network so I can only use the Ubuntu server for the logs

Linux is not my thing and the commands I have tried from the net don't work for me - it may be my lack of knowledge

Is it possible to either run the tcp dump command with something like

```
tcpdump  -n  -s 64 -i  r1_ap1  -w  > [serverIP]/home/temp
```

Or can I run the tcp dump and then run another command that tails the pcap file to another file onto the Ubuntu server?  I can use ssh and scp.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to run the tcpdump command with something like
>
> ```
> tcpdump  -n  -s 64 -i  r1_ap1  -w  > [serverIP]/home/temp
> ```

">" is done by the shell, not by tcpdump, and no UN*X shell I know of supports a mechanism to write to a remote server in that fashion.  The only way to do that would be to mount a file system from the server, but "mount a file system from a server" is the UN*X way of saying "map a network drive", and you can't do that, so....

> Or can I run the tcpdump and then run another command that tails the pcap file to another file onto the Ubuntu server? I can use ssh and scp.

```
tcpdump -n -s 64 -i r1_ap1 -w - | ssh [server] "cat >/home/temp"
```

would work, but *don't* interrupt that command by typing ^C.  Instead, interrupt it with

```
killall -SIGINT tcpdump
```

in another shell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help - your suggestion worked.  The final code I used was

```
tcpdump -n -s 64 -i r1_ap1 -w - | ssh -p[port number] root@[server IP] "cat >/home/temp/test.pcap"
```